# Trying to output all information with linq

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I've written some code that matches two arrays by the identifiers called `seqNum` and gets an answer from some math. I'm able to print out the `seqNum` and the `Answer` I get but I'm having trouble getting all of the other information that comes along with the `seqNum`. I want to be able to output something like this:

```
Name Date `seqNum` Answer...
```

My code is giving me the answer but then it just spits out the first Name in the file over and over again with different `seqNum`s and `Answer`s.

Here's the code:

```
private void executeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //NET OIL VARIANCE MATHEMATICS
    if (netOilRadBtn.Checked)
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter("testNetOil.csv"))
        {
            var items = netOil.Zip(seqNum, (oil, seq) => new { Oil = oil, Seq = seq });
            var items2 = netOil2.Zip(seqNum2, (oil, seq) => new { Oil = oil, Seq = seq });
            sw.WriteLine("Lease Name, Field Name, Reservoir, Operator, County, ST, Majo, Resv Cat, Discount Rate, Net Oil Interest, Net Gas Interest, Working Interest, Gross Wells, Ultimate Oil, Ultimate Gas, Gross Oil, Gross NGL, Gross Gas, Net Oil, Net Gas, Net NGL, Revenue To Int., Oper. Expense, Total Invest., Revenue Oil, Revenue Gas, Operating Profit, Revenue NGL, Disc Net Income, SEQ, Well ID, INC ASN, Life Years, Own Qual, Production Tax, NET OIL VARIANCE");

            foreach (var item in items.Join(items2, i => i.Seq, i => i.Seq, (a, b) => new
            {SeqID = a.Seq, Answer = this.GetTheAnswer(Convert.ToDouble(a.Oil), Convert.ToDouble(b.Oil)) 

            }))

            {
                int x = 0;
                x.Equals(item.SeqID);
                while (x != -1)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(leaseName[x] + "," + item.SeqID + "," + item.Answer);
                    x--;
                }
```

So basically I just need to print out the matching name with the correct `seqNum` and `Answer`. If anyone has any ideas or comments, that would be greatly appreciated. And my math method is pretty simple if anyone needs to see:

```
public double GetTheAnswer(double first, double second)
{
    double answer = (first - second) / second;
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: I think this is incorrect : int x = 0;
                    x.Equals(item.SeqID);. You are not assigning the value there. It needs to be int x = item.SeqID

Comment: @StephenBorg You can't do that because it says you cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: int x = Convert.ToInt32(item.SeqID). Because x, is always remaining 0 in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should include the data in the anonymous type

```
foreach (var item in items.Join(items2, i => i.Seq, i => i.Seq, (a, b) => new
   {
        SeqID = a.Seq, 
        Answer = this.GetTheAnswer(Convert.ToDouble(a.Oil),
                                   Convert.ToDouble(b.Oil)),
        Name = a.Name, // b.Name?
        Date = a.Date, // b ?
        seqNum  = a.seqNum // b ?
   }))
```

What are you trying by (`while`) looping inside the `foreach`? You loop through a collection of anonymous types that have no repetitive data in them, `item` is just a collection of flat data.

So everything after `int x = 0;` is useless. Just output the data you collect in the anonymous type row by row. Since the header ("Lease Name, Field Name, Reservoir, Operator, ...) is much longer I think there should be much more in the part `new { ... }`.

Comment: I've been trying to work this out, I understand the part where you said everything after int x = 0, but I'm not too sure how to add more things to the part new whre you put Name = a.Name and such

Comment: how would I be able to define more anonymous types like you did there?

Comment: Not more anonymous types, there should (probably) be more properties _in_ the anonymous type. But you should show sample data and desired output. I'm running blind here.

Comment: I have a bunch of arrays like this String[] leaseName2 = new String[1000]; String[] fieldName2 = new String[1000]; String[] reservoir2 = new String[1000]; and I would like the output with all the matching data from the SeqNum identifier such as... LeaseName, Field Name, Reservoir... all in one row of a csv file. The input data is all matched between two files and seqnums if that helps at all

Comment: Sorry to bother but does this help at all?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You've asked a number of questions on this piece of code now, but never showed the whole picture. If you need more help on this you should ask a question in which you either should show all sources of data involved (like: what is `item`, what is `leaseName[x]`) or (better) used a vastly slimmed down example that addresses your problem but doesn't have all the noise and side effects of the full code. The root of your problem is how to collect the data. Once you've got that right, writing them in the right order should be nothing but a simple loop in which nothing else happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the assignment of x, because you are giving it no value.

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(item.SeqID);
```

Try it and see if you get different results.